# Are these two things equal?

Tags: real-analysis

quick question on two expressions:
$$\min(\lvert X-Y\rvert, 1)=\frac{\lvert X-Y\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Y\rvert}$$
Is the above statement true, if so why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, try $X=2,Y=1${                       }